How to only show x-axis tick-labels where the effect range does not cross through 0 using plotREsim
I have conducted a logistic mixed-effects (multi-level) regression model in R and am wanting to plot the random effects using a caterpillar plot in R.
I am trying to show only the x-axis tick-labels for groups where the effect range does not cross through 0.
The plot is based on a mixed-effect regression model with the following code:
library(merTools)
model <- glmer(dependent ~ independent + (1 | strata_groups), data = data_sim, family = "binomial")
reEX1_model <- REsim(model)
plotREsim(reEX1_model, labs=TRUE)


(This image is created using simulation data. The data I am using has many more groups hence the difficulty in interpretation when including every x-axis tick label.)
reEX1_model contains the following: "groupFctr" "groupID"   "term"      "mean"      "median"    "sd"
I have tried to manually add confidence intervals to the data but the calculations are different to the effect ranges the plot gives:
Manually add confidence intervals and use ifelse() to show labels only when CI do not pass through 0:
reEX1_model <- reEX1_model %>%
  mutate(
    lower_ci = mean - 1.96 * sd,
    upper_ci = mean + 1.96 * sd,
    show_label = ifelse(lower_ci < 0 & upper_ci < 0 | lower_ci > 0 & upper_ci > 0, groupID, "") 
  )

OR
Merge information on sample size to reEX data from original data:
strata_freq <- as.data.frame(table(data_sim$strata_groups))

colnames(strata_freq) <- c("groupID", "freq")
strata_freq$groupID <- as.character(strata_freq$groupID)
reEX1_model <- merge(reEX1_model , strata_freq, by = "groupID", all.x = TRUE)
reEX1_model <- reEX1_model %>%
    mutate(
      lower_ci = mean - 1.96 * (sd / sqrt(freq)),
      upper_ci = mean + 1.96 * (sd / sqrt(freq)),
      show_label = ifelse((lower_ci > 0 | upper_ci < 0), groupID, "") 
    )

and then
plotREsim(reEX1_model , labs=TRUE) +
  ggtitle("Random Effects with Negative Estimates") +
  xlab("Random Effect Estimate") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, size = 8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10), 
        plot.title = element_text(size = 14), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = reEX1_model $show_label)
```r

As shown in the picture below the labels do not match up to the graph, whereas I need the labels to only show if the effect range crosses through 0. 

Plot after manually adding confidence intervals to reEX data:

![](https://i.sstatic.net/LhKGTzvd.png)


## The REX1_model data structure:
```r
structure(list(groupFctr = c("strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", 
"strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups", "strata_groups"
), groupID = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
"33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", 
"44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50"), term = c("(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", 
"(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)", "(Intercept)"), 
    mean = c(0.909886751144807, -0.560641994644748, -0.839010068086599, 
    -0.0855749104164985, 0.305265852623158, -1.95753051953802, 
    -1.7868914887384, 0.417890759461078, 0.0569636926705481, 
    0.264081981169611, -2.45096857561513, 1.2148580711287, -0.970315896219031, 
    1.02639782769634, 0.865207764559018, 1.7880851273379, -0.699906332397296, 
    0.725486445100463, -0.736330410345406, -0.891377616321788, 
    0.10476750925786, -1.48172137965375, 0.875473832423198, -0.597709073197813, 
    0.302782249877048, 0.113437978825481, 2.07715825818211, 0.216249675318787, 
    0.0651612840935746, -0.525806976271121, 1.1430293694878, 
    -0.658538048846008, -0.317179972927657, -0.535468211379302, 
    0.50912958721181, 0.311358770078762, 0.636320801732666, -1.44359990104475, 
    -0.178324927806782, 0.612977392484648, -0.162907767368325, 
    0.289934529926864, -1.0724193800251, 0.612898063445942, -0.400224876505546, 
    -0.0082483534151662, 0.664989772540825, -0.101955927657438, 
    -2.82795005908785, -0.152632292704985), median = c(1.30192550252992, 
    0.91854189286204, -0.314954966698868, 0.187028342045335, 
    1.70710375329869, -0.106674113613199, -0.082493692690806, 
    0.70531162883036, -0.0929286280855942, 0.0459462599477464, 
    -0.0744372951440918, -0.752791864177159, 0.397132240326663, 
    2.34467833182746, -0.547590064719462, -0.473962996036531, 
    -0.143716294631847, -0.963265809357867, -1.44631479465262, 
    -0.281991132830662, 0.439976242813436, 0.0502519992220628, 
    0.575910808858606, -0.309012913241949, 0.276892606449805, 
    1.96635693242898, -1.2337840242449, -0.00842506808630987, 
    -2.11650615067479, 1.26607310188646, -0.574050073014021, 
    2.0383375588056, -1.51318290612276, 1.24168846725956, 2.16056231846543, 
    0.0332732210613804, -0.507083511923244, -0.600282224862328, 
    -2.42713691596714, 0.31702445754317, 0.264844882213811, -1.00877361286114, 
    2.23673353418961, -1.13738608527437, -0.689419901920556, 
    0.494939987808133, -0.16713958450277, 0.79799340955947, 1.34695455516997, 
    -0.37927753092677), sd = c(1.31584216605742, 1.36246662032028, 
    1.0447764038323, 1.40517567577206, 1.08695400686355, 1.32342190170559, 
    0.965037015425875, 0.891104316623726, 0.447797931457912, 
    1.5987796440381, 1.21568020911051, 0.802017983420588, 0.660312835125425, 
    0.712584074528911, 0.78193500205873, 0.462461151794775, 1.71284958317603, 
    0.715513201041825, 1.48646669454307, 1.59738558918872, 0.953975380172808, 
    0.222001463120983, 1.42994727572521, 1.3934185773761, 1.64759856901089, 
    1.2984613593473, 0.0455595237695176, 0.74939127823055, 1.14117861672874, 
    0.711976271857851, 1.41080578709168, 1.72642115504696, 0.570925845733821, 
    0.945914974798991, 1.54312499535038, 0.928221939228138, 1.84430157131384, 
    1.46360044333536, 1.09326025801738, 1.80084866386425, 1.21068823251687, 
    0.898366272911656, 0.531341388311801, 1.37086080829839, 1.43229040985562, 
    1.81729391894403, 1.73542236144135, 0.710402213747259, 0.650378898190286, 
    0.630079925922433)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```r


PLease include some of your data using a dput() command.

As @Ben mentioned, it really helps to get better answers if you follow suggestions about writing a good R question. On your specific question, you may be able to use labellers by constructing a function that returns a blank string when CIs do not cross 0.

I was able to do this by constructing my own labels and adding an appropriate scale_x_discrete to the existing plot. I made my own example using a built-in data set.
setup
library(lme4)
library(merTools)
library(ggplot2)
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), sleepstudy)
re <- REsim(m)
pp <- plotREsim(re, labs = TRUE)

set up labels
## extract random effects
tt <- broom.mixed::tidy(m, effects = "ran_vals", conf.int = TRUE) |>
    ## put in increasing order
    dplyr::arrange(estimate) |>
    ## create labels and blank out axis-crossing values
    dplyr::mutate(labs = paste0("Subject", level),
                      labs = ifelse(conf.low<0 & conf.high>0, "", labs))


pp + scale_x_discrete(labels = tt$labs)

